# Java: multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading

Why thread of a class A waits until thread of a class B ends?
In this sample, code printing `System.out.println` never executes.
How I can fix that?

```
public class A implements Runnable {
    public A() {
        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A tmp = new A();
    }
    public void run() {

        B tmp = new B();
        tmp.run();

        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
class B implements Runnable {
    public B() {
    }
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you start thread A calling the start method but thread B calling the run????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tmp.run();
```

runs in main thread instead of separate `Thread` since you have not started B as a separate thread.

Above line should be replaced with

```
new Thread(tmp).start();
```

You have started Thread A properly (by using start() method)  and did not replicated the same for Thread B.

Refer to oracle documentation link about starting Threads in two [ways](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html) :

1. *Provide a Runnable object:* The `Runnable` interface defines a single method, run, meant to contain the code executed in the thread.
2. *Subclass Thread:* The Thread class itself implements Runnable, though its run method does nothing. An application can subclass Thread, providing its own implementation of run

On a different note, your Thread B runs in infinite loop and don't have exit condition. If it's not intended, add a exit condition in `run()` method.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code:

```
B tmp = new B();
tmp.run();

System.out.println("Hello");
```

Doesn't start a thread. There's only one Thread spawned, which calls `b.run()`. So Thread `a` simply hangs in the endless-loop in `b.run()`. Just create another thread for the runnable `b' and everything should work as expected:

```
public void run() {

    Thread t = new Thread(new B());
    t.start();

    System.out.println("Hello");
}
```

Comment: the phrase "Doesn't start a thread" is a bit misleading. the runnable runs in the main thread instead of a separate one

Comment: @mangusta what would be misleading about that? You just said it yourself: the code doesn't start a new thread, but executes directly in the main-thread